# Convert columns with certain column names from factor to character

Tags: r, casting, type-conversion

I have a large dataset with few 100 columns. Some of the columns are of type factor. I want to convert these columns from `factor` to `character`. I know in can convert them individually using the function `as.character` like this below

```
     df$col_test_1 = as.character(df$col_test_1)
```

However I am looking for an efficient way to convert all columns that have a certain common string in their column name for example `_test_` . Convert all columns where their column name contains the string `_test_` from `factor` to `character`. Any suggestions or tips on how to do this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `grepl("_test_",col_test_1)`

Comment: @MFR, I am aware of that, but not sure how to use `grepl`+ `as.character`  on the column names retrived from the `grepl` function

Comment: you need to give us a reproducible example. Then we can try our code and post am answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basic approach would work, although it is not clear what exactly are your requirements for it being efficient.

```
df <- data.frame(my_test_col=as.factor(c(1,2,3)), my_other_col=as.factor(c(4,5,6)))

for (colname in colnames(df)) {
  if (grepl('_test_', colname)){
    df[[colname]] <- as.character(df[[colname]])
  }
}
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks mpdem